# Using Sed To Search/Replace Variable In Bash Script

Tags: bash, unix, ubuntu, sed

I'm trying to change the date in the first line of a text file by using Sed to replace the previous days date with the current days date.

Below is the code from the bash script that I'm trying to use to accomplish this:

```
YMD=$(date +%Y%m%d)

ODA=$(date -u +%Y%m%d --date="1 days ago")

mv ${HOMEDIR}/${PATH1}/nws_${VAR}_conus_daily_${ODA}.ctl ${HOMEDIR}/${PATH1}/nws_${VAR}_conus_daily_${YMD}.ctl

sed "s/${ODA}/${YMD}/" ${HOMEDIR}/${PATH1}/nws_${VAR}_conus_daily_${YMD}.ctl

URL1=http://water.weather.gov/${VAR}/p_download_new/${Y}/${M}/${D}/nws_${VAR}_conus_${YMD}.nc

wget -P ${HOMEDIR}/${PATH1}/ -N ${URL1}
```

The first line in the text file reads as follows:

```
dset ^grads/data/ahps/nws_precip_conus_20140423.nc
```

Comment: What is problem with your sed?

Comment: Can you show output of `cat -vte file.txt`?

Comment: http://paste2.org/ZUAPMYt9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want sed to change your file, you have to give the `-i` option, like so:

```
sed -i "s/${ODA}/${YMD}/" ${HOMEDIR}/${PATH1}/nws_${VAR}_conus_daily_${YMD}.ctl
```

Otherwise `sed` will just output the changed file to standard output.

Comment: Hi Sigi! Adding "-i" option after the sed command worked like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
sed "1s/[0-9]\+\.nc/$(date +%Y%m%d).nc/" file.txt
```

It replace the numbers before `.nc` in the first line of `file.txt` with the output of

```
date +%Y%m%d
```

which outputs the current date in the desired format.

---

**Proof of functionality**:

Having `file.txt` as this:

```
dset ^grads/data/ahps/nws_precip_conus_20140421.nc
bla bla 20140421.nc
```

Issue the above command:

```
sed "1s/[0-9]\+\.nc/$(date +%Y%m%d).nc/" file.txt
```

Output:

```
dset ^grads/data/ahps/nws_precip_conus_20140423.nc
bla bla 20140421.nc
```

You see that the date in the first line and only that has been replaced by the current date.

Comment: Hi, I tried using that code but, it still refuses to change the previous days date to the current days date in the first line... Currently, I've got this: sed "1s/[0-9]\+\.nc/$(date +%Y%m%d).nc/" ${HOMEDIR}/${PATH1}/nws_${VAR}_conus_daily_${YMD}.ctl

Comment: I wonder why this isn't working on my end... Here's the full bash script: http://paste2.org/1Yh8LcDp Do you spot anything that might be causing this to not work?

Comment: Thank you. I should also mention that I was just able to get your sample to work in the terminal but, it won't change the line inside the actual file...